# Copying symbolic links and filenames with special characters to NAS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nas, symbolic-link, special-characters

I have a new Western Digital My Book Live NAS. I am trying to copy files from an old drive to the NAS. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I've mounted the drive by browsing the network in Nautilus and choosing a shared folder configured on the NAS. The shared folder is then automatically mounted at `.gvfs/files on mybooklive`.

There are two problems so far:

1. File names and directory names containing certain characters (e.g. `:` or `|`). Attempting to copy these results in the error message:

   cp: cannot stat `/path/to/destination.filename': Invalid argument
2. Symbolic links. In Nautilus I get the error message: `Symlinks not supported by backend`

My questions are:

1. Can I connect to the NAS or configure the NAS so that I can copy my files without this problem? (In case it matters, I don't need Windows compatibility.)
2. If not, what can I do to identify all the problem files?
3. Can I do anything to automatically fix my filenames

Please let me know if any of this needs clarification. I'm not too familiar with all of this so I may have left out some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Given your symptoms, I'm going to assume that you're mounting this NAS volume via SMB instead of NFS.  Try using NFS if at all possible.